# How to set 50% height on a child div of an auto height div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, percentage

I want to set up a block made of 3 cells:

[image: This is how I want to set it up]

The parent div is set to 100% width, the two columns are 50% width. The content needs to expand/shrink with the page as it will be a responsive page.
Since I don't know the height of the parent div, I can only set the rows on the right a percentage height, but 50% is not valid with an auto height parent.
How Can I achive to have the upper and lover half 50% of the height of the parent div?
The image's aspect ratio will always be 1:1

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column blue"><img src="square.png"></div><!--
--><div class="column yellow"><!--
    --><div class="row green">Upper half</div><!--
    --><div class="row red">Lower half</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    padding 0;
    margin 0;
    border: none;
}
.column {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here's my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/7y9eK/

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS like below.

```
.column {
width: 50%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}
.red {
background-color: red;
height:50%;
}
.green {
background-color: green;
height:50%;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/7y9eK/14/

Comment: Ok. I have updated my jsfiddle. Now it will work in firefox also.

Comment: Now failed in IE11 :(

Comment: I have two problems with this: 1. This only goes as wide as the image itself, but in certain situations I'll need to scale the image larger than it's native resolution. 2. This has to be working in IE8 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle with desired output please go through the link:
[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9eK/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    padding 0;
    margin 0;
    border: none;
}
.column {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column blue"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Tiling_Regular_4-4_Square.svg/320px-Tiling_Regular_4-4_Square.svg.png"></div><!--
    --><div class="column yellow"><!--
        --><div class="row green">Upper half</div><!--
        --><div class="row red">Lower half</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still not the desired effect. The boxes on the right don't align with the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
// test you this code 

.container {
      width: 1000px;
      display: table;
      border:1x solid #ddd;
       margin:10px auto;
 }
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.column {
     width: 50%;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align:top;
  }

   .row {
      display:table-row;
 }
 .red,.green {
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
    height:250px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
   }
   .green {
    background-color: green;
    }
  .blue {
    background-color: blue;
     }
  .yellow {
     background-color: yellow;
    }

   // html code test 

   <div class="container">
    <div class="column blue">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Tiling_Regular_4-4_Square.svg/320px-Tiling_Regular_4-4_Square.svg.png">
    </div>

    <div class="column yellow">
        <div style="display:table;width:100%">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="green">
                    upper half
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="red">
                    Lower half
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This won't help me, as I need the container to fill the width of the window. I won't be asking this if I can set a fixed width, but this will be a responsive page with fluid widths!

Answer (score -1):

with javascript and jquery

```
(function myFunction() {

    var imgHeight = $("img").outerHeight(true);
    jQuery('.column').css('height', (imgHeight) + "px");
    $(window).resize(function () {
        myFunction();
    });
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/7y9eK/13/

i changed some css too.

basically this catches the height of the image and it appends it to the columns, this way your columns have a set px height and the 50% height for the rows now work because's their parent have a fixed height, even if it's dynamic (works on resize too!)

Comment: The resize seems to be extremely slow with this method. Also I want to avoid using javascript if possible.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible by css only. You have to use below js for this.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        var container = $('.container');
        var imgContainer = $('.container img');
        if (container.length && imgContainer.length) {
            container.innerHeight(imgContainer.height());
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var container = $('.container');
        var imgContainer = $('.container img');
        if (container.length && imgContainer.length) {
            container.innerHeight(imgContainer.height());
        }
    });
</script>
```

And have to add height:100% to column class. so the updated class will look like this:

```
.column {
width: 50%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this method, although it uses javascript and doesn't work on IE...